# WPF: How to style the individual RepeatButton of a Slider control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, custom-controls

I would like to style a slider such that I can assign a color to the track on the left side of the thumb, and a different color to the track on the right side of the thumb. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383251/how-to-style-the-slider-control-in-wpf) but it only deals with a single style that's shared among both track pieces (on both sides of the thumb).

[image: Example of the desired outcome]

Comment: I think you need to replace the entire slider template. You can then either colour the track using a lineargradientbrush and make the repeat buttons transparent https://i.imgur.com/fHZDUW5.png.  Or style each repeatbutton like each of the 100 vertical sliders here https://i.imgur.com/3pC3yU6.png.

Comment: @Andy hi, that's indeed what I'm looking to do but I'm new to WPF. Could you share your template by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Andy's comment, I extracted the default Slider control template by right clicking on the control and selecting Edit Copy. I personally don't need to show any tick values, so I decided to change the slider's Minimum and Maximum properties to 0 and 1 respectively.

I bodged around a bit with the code from [this answer regarding gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546863/11808605) to change the Slider's Track Background a LinearGradientBrush between 0,0 and 1,0 where the offset (where the two colours are separated) is bound to the Slider's value (conveniently between 0 and 1). In code, it looks like this:

```xml
<!-- From the Slider's default control template -->
<Border x:Name="TrackBackground" ...>
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Value}" />
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}, Path=Value}" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    ...
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the vertical slider template.

You will have a number of differences, particularly in your thumb.

I have some fairly specific requirements for this thing.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GraphSliderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="#FFD6D6D6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFE7EAEA" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5" Width="6">
                    <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Visibility="Hidden" Width="6"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge">
                            <RepeatButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Salmon" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </RepeatButton.Style>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge">
                            <RepeatButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </RepeatButton.Style>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" 
                                   Height="6"
                                   Width="6"
                                   OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                   IsHitTestVisible="True"
                                   >
                            <Thumb.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="True"
                                          >
                                        <Path x:Name="grip" Data="{StaticResource FlatStar}" Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="DarkRed"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFDCECFC"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFDAECFC"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Thumb.Template>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! I've already bodged a solution that works for my horizontal slider but this detailed template will surely help as well!